# jquery tool tip plugin issue when text size changed in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am using the jQuery tooltip plugin wtooltip.  Here's a [link](http://wayfarerweb.com/wtooltip.php) to the wtooltip.

I am facing an issue with this.  It works perfectly fine when the browser is at normal text size (100%).  But when I change it to say 110%, the tooltip position changes.  Similarly, when I change it to 90%, it shifts from the position.  I also tried [qTip](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/&rct=j&q=qtip&ei=6_hfTr6zOMmRgQeunqCAAg&usg=AFQjCNEDxvPkKUnmcYrwHq8eGDJ_niJtRQ&sig2=JNHaPJ2F4-E4euEcTlVhzg&cad=rja) and [SimpleTip](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/&rct=j&q=simpletip&ei=_fhfTre2GorEgAfUrpGNAg&usg=AFQjCNGJZo2jvKBK0d5tI_Tbk5POOeoxag&sig2=nlHE3CvUnYf_KEyJZwbuZA&cad=rja), but both are giving the same problem.  What should I do to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: Do you mean you're adjusting the view (zoom) percentage of the browser, or that you're trying to adjust the size of text in the tooltip?

Comment: I mean the zoom percentage of browser.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.